# GPG. Смена парольной фразы

Tags: linux, password, gpg

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сменить парольную фразу, которую запрашивает GPG?
P.S.
OS: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам ответил.
Делается это командой `gpg --passwd --change-passphrase userID` .
Может кому пригодится на будущее...